# Ruby gem names with appended ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ruby gem names are really throwing me off. For example if install a gem called jade, a wrapper script is placed at /usr/bin/jade1.9 on some systems and at /usr/bin/jade on others. I'm curious if anyone has a recommendation on how I can use jade in scripts without writing some hackish code that guesses the correct gem name. The naming also makes it difficult to write documentation for less savvy users. Is there a simple way of making gems install with same name on all systems?

To elaborate a bit:

```
gem install jade #jade is something I made up
ls /usr/bin/|grep "jade"
> jade1.9
```

When I want to execute:

```
jade --dosomething
```

I actually have to run

```
jade1.9 --dosomething
```

I've noticed certain gems such as rake are installed at both /usr/bin/rake and /usr/bin/rake1.9 with neither being a symlink and both files having the same md5sum.

I am trying to understand why gems get the ruby version appended on some systems and how I can make install without the trailing version number.

A list of some example of gems that install an executable:

```
ls /usr/bin/|grep "1.9"
amalgalite-pack1.9
bundle1.9
crate1.9
erb1.9
gem1.9
irb1.9
minitar1.9
rake1.9
rdoc1.9
ri1.9
rlock1.9
ruby1.9
rubyscript2exe1.9
testrb1.9
```

Comment: You should not usually need to worry about location of the gem when `require`-ing it. A combination of libraries take care of managing your path for you. On a typical development box, this is combined behaviour of **RVM**, **Bundler** and **Rubygems** (the last one has been an integral part of Ruby distribution since version 1.9). Do you have a specific problem with accessing an installed gem?

Comment: Please demo the issue you're having

Comment: The edit gives the question more sense, except *most* gems don't install command line utilities. So your problem is only with some fraction of the gems that do. Could you name a gem that you have installed that behaves like `jade` (I have never had to reference a versioned command-line script for any gem I have used, and I have installed a few)?

Comment: Ugh, **RVM** suggestions/recommendations are starting to get old. /me flushed that Toiletware™ a long time ago.

Comment: @naomik: Not the forum for arguing relative merits - just suggest the alternative you are using. **rbenv**?

Comment: @JeffC: Most, if not all, of your examples should *just work* by typing the un-versioned name. Are you saying that all the items on that list require you to type the full name you see in that folder? If so, you have some problem with your Ruby installation.