# Ruby Gem Bin Name with Ruby Version Appended

Tags: ruby, rubygems

After installing a Ruby gem system-wide, the binary name of the gem is always appended with a ruby version. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm new to Ruby. So I was checking out some ruby vim plugins and some of them require to install some gems. So I installed the gem system-wide using `sudo gem install rubocop` for example, but after installation I was not able to execute the `rubocop` bin in terminal. Instead, I had to run `rubocop.ruby2.5`. Why is the ruby version always appended? How do I get rid of this? Might be a dumb question but I really appreciate some help. I checked a similar post [Ruby gem names with appended ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798660/ruby-gem-names-with-appended-ruby-version) but it didn't help me much. The following is the bin name and location. I'm using openSUSE and Ruby 2.5.3.

```
~ $ which rubocop.ruby2.5 
/usr/bin/rubocop.ruby2.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not RubyGems appends the Ruby version number to the executable name is governed by [the `--[no-]format-executable` flag to `gem install`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#installupdate-options).

If you don't want the version suffix, you can either use

```
gem install --no-format-executable <somegem>
```

Or set this flag in one of your RubyGems configuration files.

My guess is that your Linux distribution has this configuration flag set for globally so that gem executables installed for different Ruby versions don't clobber each other.